# how to prevent number hyperlinks on android devices in microsoft teams message cards

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

we currently are building a connector for Microsoft teams, whenever we include a number in the message card that we send, on ios, and web teams apps it's looking fine, however on android devices all numbers in the cards, can be either prices or even time related numbers, are being converted to hyperlinks.

does anyone know how to prevent this default behaviour of converting numbers to links in these message cards?

Comment: Hi, can you send json payload for the card that you are sending

Answer (score 0):

Must likely you have an app (pre) installed on Android that does this conversion. This is not something teams does. If you need more info then please start by sharing the actual json for the adaptive card that is posted